# python manage.py runserver: django.db.utils.OperationalError

Tags: django, python-2.7

I cloned a git django website project which includes php and sql. I am running Python 2.7 on Windows 10.

After running python manage.py runserver to test local changes to my files I receive the following error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"

I have not yet been able to start the Django runserver to checkout the changes. I am new to Python and Django and would appreciate any help!

Comment: post the content of your setting file

Answer (score 0):

I guess the repository who have cloned has some database information, which it uses to connect to the sql when you run that manage.py runserver.
   Open the settings.py , search for 'DATABASES'
`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': DB NAME,
        'USER': DB USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': DB PASSWORD,
        'HOST': DB HOST IP,               
        'PORT': '3306', 

    } }
```

`

Edit this part with your database details and then try running the code.

 **Note:** Make sure that database information provided is valid and you are able to connect to it before providing here .
'''